# Route spotify traffic via direct inet, all other via VPN

Tags: vpn, routing

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and have a VPN connection to work. I'd like to leave practically all traffic going through the tunnel so that my machine doesn't become a security vulnerability for my work network. However I feel a bit silly getting my spotify music through the VPN. Two questions:

1. Does anyone have any reasons why this might be a bad idea?
2. How do I do it? :)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called split tunnelling. A [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/17963/bypass-vpn-for-certain-apps) asked something similar, but there weren't many useful answers.

To do this you'd need to identify the spotify traffic. This might be a problem because while some of the data goes to/from TCP port 4070 on Spotify's server, it also uses peer-to-peer transfer to other users of the client on a variety of different ports. Therefore it would probably be tricky to configure the VPN to ensure all Spotify traffic didn't go through the VPN.

The details of how to set up split tunnelling depends on which VPN software that you're using.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's the problem. I was hoping there might be a way to identify the traffic based on the process and route it through the local gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cisco VPN client (I think all vpn clients will have this option, though not tried)  -

- Disconnect from Cisco VPN
- Click on Transport tab
- Un-check "Enable local LAN access"
- Reconnect

Now you should be able to use your Spotify while connected to vpn.

```
What does "Enable local LAN access" means?
```

*VPN Clients to **only** access their local LAN while tunnelled into a VPN*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but I'm not sure you're answering the question. I was interested in splitting up the traffic between the VPN and the local gateway, with _only_ Spotify traffic going locally.