# How to route only work traffic when connected to company VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

Let's say that the company has a policy that forbids listenning to internet radios using their connectivity.

Now, I'm working from home, connected to company VPN to have access to intranet, databases and version control, but I'd like to listen to internet radios from my own connection. I am sure that the internet radio data now flows through the VPN, because everything goes through that VPN when I'm connected.

Is there a way to set up traffic (I have Windows 7 x64) so that only traffic addressed to 192.168.* addresses would go through VPN and all other through my home connection directly?

Thanks

Comment: already answered http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network http://superuser.com/questions/17963/bypass-vpn-for-certain-apps

Answer (score 3):

Many proprietary VPN clients prohibit any tampering as this would allow setting up tunnel to company network.

However, first check out your route table. Assuming windows, type **route print**.

Find your gateway going to the company, as 0.0.0.0 is pointing to it. On another line this IP is pointing your local network gateway. Find all your company IPs, set them to use your company gateway IP and change 0.0.0.0 to go to your local network gateway.

Or, more simple, set your internet radio webpage go through your local network gateway.
e.g.

```
route add 195.93.80.47 192.168.0.1
```

Third option is to use another computer for radio. I once had this dedicated hardware for radio. It was about ten inches times four inches times eight inches and had batteries inside it.