# How to block internet via certain network in Windows ?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I got work laptop and I connect to corporate network. The admins take statistics of me being logged in and also the usage of internet.

I don'tlike to be watched, thus, I purchased mobile internet connection and run on internet via that. However, I still want to be on the corporate network and use it locally.

How can I achieve this at once in Windows 7 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to route only work traffic when connected to company VPN?](http://superuser.com/questions/309042/how-to-route-only-work-traffic-when-connected-to-company-vpn) and [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

Comment: @Greenleader - You won't be able to connect to the corporate network and use your own internet connection.  There are ways to do it ( VPN ) that requires the assistance of your network admins.

Answer (score 1):

Set a static route to your corporate network(s).  Set the default route to your mobile internet provider.

Comment: The original question does not say a VPN is being used.  My Win7 desktop in work does not use a VPN, and I accomplish exactly what was asked using exactly what I described.