# How to stop split tunnelling over cisco VPN (OS X)?

Tags: macos, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec, split-tunnel

I'm using OS X (Snow Leopard) and the built in Cisco IP Sec client to connect to my corporate VPN.  Currently, everything works as designed, and desired for most people.  However, I would like to be able to funnel all traffic (particularly all web browser traffic) through the VPN.  (Note - I'm an end user here, not the network administrator).  Is this possible?

In searching around, most people are looking to do the opposite; break out the VPN and enable split tunnelling of data.  I'd like to avoid the split tunnelling.  Is there some setting I can make in my OS X client to make this happen?  I ran across a post where routing table changes are made to force split tunnelling:

[How to force split tunnel routing on Mac to a Cisco VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/91191/how-to-force-split-tunnel-routing-on-mac-cisco-vpn)

I'm thinking something similar to that might work, but I'm not a networking expert so I'm not sure where to start (or if it is even possible).

Thank you!

Notre

Answer (score -1):

There is NO NEED to change anything to avoid split tunneling as there will always be ALL the traffic routed through the tunnel if you do not change anything.
So just calm down and use the built-in VPN IPSec (CISCO) client in MacOSX (10.7 to 10.9) and all your traffic will be routed through the tunnel.

Comment: This is incorrect.  If a tunnel is configured as split, only traffic destined for routes configured in the route table by the VPN client will route over the VPN.