# routing single application through any kind of vpn on OSX

Tags: macos, routing, squid, socks

OSX Application should run through manually selected route (vpn connection). 
Best idea I had is to put squid on separate linux machine, setup VPN on that machine and make iproute (shorewall) handle squid traffic through vpn. OSX has global proxy settings so unfortunately I can't handle single application through my remote proxy.

Suggestions including socks, per application routing solutions are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to selectively route network traffic through VPN on Mac OS X Leopard?](http://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard)