# Mac OS X and VPN Option all traffic over vpn

Tags: macos, networking, mac, vpn, routing

i have to say, i am new in using a Mac. So please don't expect too much. My operating system is Mac OS X 10.9.2.

To connect to my company's pc, i managed to create a vpn connection using VPN (PPTP). This is done by the use of the Mac OS VPN client. The connection works and i can use Microsoft Remote Desktop.

I don't want to send all traffic over vpn. Mail, http, should work using my private connection. As far as i know, the new Mac OS tries to use the local connection, and if not successful it redirects traffic down to the vpn connection? Therefore the checkbox Send all traffic over VPN is not checked (vpn settings).

Now the strange thing: 
Sometimes i can connect to my company's pc and sometimes i cannot. If i restart my MacBook the connection works again (send all traffic is still not checked) So in case it doesn't work, i have to check the "Send all traffic option" or reboot my Mac.

I really hope you have any ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is called split tunnel. Here are some old threads with info that may work on Mavericks too: https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703849/possible-to-configure-os-x-vpn-to-split-traffic-between-vpn-and-local-interface

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read those comments before but the strange thing is why is it working after a reboot? I have a colleague he can use the vpn without any manipulation (also Mac and Send all traffic not set). Isn't it true that MacOS routes automatically with the preference on the local connection?

Comment: My guess is that there may be timeout issue that is getting fixed by restarting the machine. Have you tried disconnecting and connecting the VPN rather than restarting the machine? You may also try to enable verbose logging, and see what it says. As for what exactly "Send all traffic over VPN" does, I am not sure, but according to an answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39290/what-traffic-is-sent-over-the-build-in-vpn-connection it may depend on the VPN server settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay i verified the problem again. At first it works and a few minutes later, i cannot establish the connection again. I tried to disconnect and reconnect the vpn connection without reboot, no improvement. Thanks for your suggestion concerning verbose logging. I did that. The file seems very complex to me. The only thing i recognise is a message "No dhcp server replied". Is it possible that there might be a problem between local subnet mask 192.168.. and 10.31..? I am not an expert in network configuration.

Comment: okay here is an interesting update. At first I start the Mac and connect to my vpn. A route is added, I can verify this with netstat -r. Later i disconnect and try it again. There is no route and I can not connect Remote Desktop using the VPN. The route is lost. Manually adding the with route add makes the thing working again. I hope anyone of you can help me / give me a hint why the route is lost. Thanks