# How to selectively route traffic for Cisco IPSec on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec

I am working from home and have to be connected to our Cisco VPN to access certain websites, such as self-hosted GitHub.

Is there away to configure the VPN to only be used for self-hosted GitHub and the rest of the traffic to *not* use it?

I have found this article: https://akrabat.com/routing-specific-traffic-to-the-vpn-on-os-x/ and this one [How to selectively route network traffic through VPN on Mac OS X Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard?newreg=09186b96784446a39cc766eab24856af) but they both refer to L2TP where there is a checkbox for "send all traffic over VPN connection" that can be unchecked.

Is it possible to do the same with a Cisco IPSec VPN connection?